# Issue with alphanumerics using a variable to populate an SQL db

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Trying to update a mysql db by clicking a close button and updating the status attribute with "0" and echo'ing a "closed" verbiage.  The current code I inherited from someone else updates the db if the job number is only numeric integers.  When the job number is an alphanumeric or just alpha I get an error message:

UPDATE not successful: Unknown column 'test5' in 'where clause'

Initial updateTable comes from this function in a functions.php file:

```
function updateTable($table, $update, $where){
        $query = ("UPDATE $table "."SET $update "."WHERE $where ");
        $result = mysql_query($query) 
        or die("UPDATE not successful: " . mysql_error()); 
}
```

The closing of the record and update to mysql is done with this code:

```
if($_SESSION['login']){
include("functions.php");
$currentPOJO = $_GET["pojo"];
dbConnect();
$where = "pojo_number=".$currentPOJO;
updateTable("records", "status=0", $where);
echo "closed";
```

}

I have tried several changes with no luck.  What am I missing?

Again updating a column in a db with "0" to signify closure of a record.  The job number or "pojo" has to be able to have both alpha and numeric chars.

**NOTE**  - My mysql db has the "status" attribute/column set to,  varChar(35).

Thanks for any help possible.

Comment: Your error has to do with the where clause, so whatever is calling your updateTable function is sending the wrong information, be it alphanumeric or not.

Comment: This reeks of SQL injection vulnerabilities.  My suggestion is to use something like prepared statements to handle your data.

Also, slap a `var_dump($query)` inside `updateTable`.  Might give you some insight as to where 'test5' is coming in.

Comment: First, you don't need quotes, `UPDATE $table SET $update WHERE $where`, second, the error is in your `$where` condition, can you make a `print_r($where);`?

Comment: Adding the var_dump($query) or the print_r($where); produce a new error:   string(52) "UPDATE records SET status=0 WHERE pojo_number=test5 " UPDATE not successful: Unknown column 'test5' in 'where clause'  thanks side note: there is another function for the sql security @GigaWatt also this app lives within a secure network not for public consumption :)  thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a set of quotes:

`$where = "pojo_number='". $currentPOJO ."'";`

That makes the query change from:
`WHERE pojo_number=test5` to `WHERE pojo_number='test5'`